# I want to show in every Post with the user_name creator of post

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (fdsfsd, dfds, 2020-06-09 16:32:53, 2020-06-09 16:32:53))
```

This is the PostsController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'title'=>'required',
        'body'=>'required'
    ]);
    $post = new  Post ;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body= $request->input('body');
    $post->save();
    return redirect('/posts')->with('success','Post created');
}
```

and this is the migration i've done

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('posts',function($table){
    $table->String('user_name');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('posts',function($table){
        $table->dropColumn('user_name');
        });
    }
}
```

when I type this : php artisan migrate:rollback , the store fucntion work perfectly , but the post doesn't have the name of user that created it

and thanks for advance .

Comment: The error says you need to send `user_id` column while you are creating post. Your controller is missing that part.

Comment: @Ersoy so if i add this ligne to store function : $post->user_name= $request->('use_name');   it will work ??

Comment: No it won’t - you need to get user($user) by username first, then $post->user_id= $user->id

Answer (score 0):

you have many weak points in your code ....

the column 'user_name' its place is 'users' table not 'posts' table, so your migration should not take place ....

you must set 'user_id' in store method and in $fillable in Post model like:

```
class Post extends Model
{
$protected $fillable=['title','body','user_id'];
public function user()
{
return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
}
}
```

then .. in your controller you must get 'user_id' from the current logged in user:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'title'=>'required',
        'body'=>'required'
    ]);
    $post = new  Post() ;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body= $request->input('body');
$post->user_id=$request->user()->id;
    $post->save();
    return redirect('/posts')->with('success','Post created');
}
```

you must be sure of that the route that is bound to this controller method should have auth middleware ...

now: if you want to get post with user name:

```
$postWithUserName=Post::where('id',$post_id)->with('user:id,name')->get();
```

make sure you have a column 'name' in users table ...